# URL from one page to another page + region

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a page with a master header and need to go from a second page back to the 'index' to a region. This will get me to the page but I cannot seem to get to the region which is #about.

```
<a runat="server" href="~Index.aspx"  class="smoothScroll">
   About
 </a>
```

Comment: You mean as soon as you redirect to **Index.aspx**  your page should scroll to **#About** region /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should give the about region an id, and then link to that page and at the end of it add #(our id) like this:

```
<div id="about"></div>
```

and in your link:

```
<a runat="server" href="~/Index.aspx#about"  class="smoothScroll">
   About
 </a>
```